# Unable to use antd FormItem after following example exactly

Tags: reactjs, antd

Following the [example code](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-coordinated) exactly. I have encountered this error
    [image]. Only when i excluded wrapping the input with FormItem that the error disappeared. Anyone else having this issue? I followed the code exactly.

Using 
antd@3.10.7
react@16.5.2

My code: 
    import React from 'react';
    import { Form, Select, Input, Button } from 'antd';

```
const FormItem = Form.Item;
const Option = Select.Option;

class NewForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
          if (!err) {
            console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
          }
        });
      }

      handleSelectChange = (value) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
          note: `Hi, ${value === 'male' ? 'man' : 'lady'}!`,
        });
      }

    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        const hi = <Input />;
        console.log('hi', hi, typeof hi);
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <FormItem>
                        {getFieldDecorator('note', {
                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your note!' }],
                    })(<Input />)}
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem>
                        {getFieldDecorator('gender', {
                        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select your gender!' }],
                    })(
                        <Select
                        placeholder="Select a option and change input text above"
                        onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
                        >
                        <Option value="male">male</Option>
                        <Option value="female">female</Option>
                        </Select>
                    )}
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem >
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </FormItem>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}


export default Form.create()(NewForm);
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Because when I am running exact code there is no error. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wpwxnoro9)

Comment: Shared my code. Its exactly the same. I can't load your demo thou

Comment: Your shared code working fine. I cannot find any error. Check the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wl4rpvrk7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the error by upgrading the following webpack modules. Hope it helps anyone else who comes along.

Old package.json

```
"@babel/cli": "7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0-beta.55",
```

New package.json

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
"@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
```